# Use sass extended placeholder with additional classes

Tags: css, sass

I made this sass placeholder for a default button and there should be additional buttons like a success or danger button.

This is my sass placeholder in short:

```
%button {
  border: none;
  background-color: $default-color;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: $default-color-text;
}

%button-danger {
  @extend %button;
  background-color: $default-color-danger;
  color: $default-color-danger-text;
}

%button-success {
  @extend %button;
  background-color: $default-color-success;
  color: $default-color-success-text;
}
```

Now i want to extend from these buttons and make an element with a class to a button and with additional classes to a danger/success button.

```
.button {
  @extend %button;

  &.danger {
    @extend %button-danger;
  }

  &.success {
    @extend %button-success;
  }
}
```

The result is

```
.button.danger, .button.success, .button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff; }

.button.danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  color: #fff; }

.button.success {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: #fff; }
```

Thats correct, but i think of a lot of different buttons and there could be a shorter way like that:

```
.button { /* only one class in this directive */
  border: none;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff; }

.button.danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  color: #fff; }

.button.success {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: #fff; }
```

Is there a way to compile this result, or is that not recommendable?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  If you don't want to extend the .button styles, don't extend them.

Comment: Where are the `.success-btn, button` selectors coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the extend from %button-danger and %button-success.

```
%button {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

%button-danger {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}

%button-success {
  background-color: green;
  color: green;
}


.button {
  @extend %button;

  &.danger {
    @extend %button-danger;
  }

  &.success {
    @extend %button-success;
  }
}
```

Comment: But now there is no possibility to extend directly from %button-success